# Childbrowser in Cordova 2.1.0 is not working

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I am upgrading Phonegap 1.4.1 to Cordova 2.1.0. I got an error in childbrowser.java. what are the changes I need to make, so that Childbrowser works?

I am getting many errors in childbrowser.java starting from the import line:

```
import com.phonegap.api.PhonegapActivity;
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
```

So, how to replace Phonegap 1.4.1 to Cordova 2.1.0 in Android mobile applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser/tree/master/www) with a full explanation.

Thanks.